# Android:Keyboard not shown using code in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, keyboard

This code is to show and hide Android Keyboard on a button click.

```
public void keyClickHandler(View v) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.KeyBoard);
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    if (keyboard) {
        mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        keyboard = false;
    } else {
        mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        keyboard = true;
    }

    Log.d("SET", "Focus");
}
```

But it is `not` working in emulator

I got found that it is working in the phone,but `not` in the emulator

Comment: Can you tell me if this code resides in an `Activity` or a `Dialog` based class? I have personally had problems with displaying the IME in  `AlertDialog` based classes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the rest of your code is, but you can try something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.KeyBoard);
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

     switch(v.getId())
     {
         case R.id.yourButtonId:
            if(keyboard)
            {
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                keyboard = false;
            } 
            else 
            {
                mgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                keyboard = true;
            }

            Log.d("SET", "Focus");
            break;
     }
}
```

For this to work you have to implement your class with onClickListener and in onCreate set your button to something like this:

```
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: What is not working? Is it just the button that doesn't work on the emulator?

Comment: by pressing that button, i am getting Keyboard shown in the real phone,but while working in emulator,it does not show the keyboard